# Match Before and After a pattern in Python RE

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following strings.

```
string1 = "按照由 GPV 提供的相关报告; 世界卫生组织 WHO 发布的有关研究"
string2 = "\n\n 介绍 INTRODUCTION"
```

How can I remove the spaces between Chinese characters and English acronyms?

The expected result is:
`"按照由GPV提供的相关报告; 世界卫生组织WHO发布的有关研究"`.

However, the re pattern should **not** remove the space between `介绍` and `INTRODUCTION` since there are no Chinese characters on the right side of `INTRODUCTION`.

Comment: Share your expected output?

Comment: So, you want to remove the whitespaces after Chinese and English acronyms only if English acronym has sime Chinese acronym after it?

Comment: Yes. @MayankPorwal

Comment: @Aaron Do you mean re.sub(r"\p{Han}+\s+\p{Latin}+\s+\p{Han}+", "", string)?

Comment: @JamesChang I just realized it doesn't work as is in python ; I'm checking if there's an alternate syntax

Comment: I believe the third-party module [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) implements `\p{script}` if you care to use it

Comment: @Aaron I tried regex.sub(r"\p{Han}+\s+\p{Latin}+\s+\p{Han}+", "", string) and got nothing.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have any environment where I could try it right now, but [the module's doc](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex) makes me think it should work (search for "Unicode codepoint properties", you'll get a section which describes how to match scripts)

Comment: You might be needing an UNICODE flag, I'm not sure how to understand this: "If neither the ASCII, LOCALE nor UNICODE flag is specified, it will default to UNICODE if the regex pattern is a Unicode string and ASCII if it’s a bytestring."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the third-party regex implementation module [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), it supports `\p{script}` tokens which make this task easy :

```
\p{Han}+\s+\p{Latin}+\s+\p{Han}+
```

Python native `re`'s unfortunately doesn't support these.

In order to remove the spaces, use capturing groups to select the surrounding words and refer to those in your replacement pattern :

```
Match          (\p{Han}+)\s+(\p{Latin}+)\s+(\p{Han}+)
Replace by     \1\2\3
```

Comment: There should be some combinations of looking ahead / behind involved, I guess? The difficult part of this problem is to figure out the use of multiple look ahead / behind.

Comment: @JamesChang What exaclty do you want to match? You said the expected result was ""按照由GPV提供的相关报告; 世界卫生组织WHO发布的有关研究"", which my regex [matches](https://regex101.com/r/ptZp9l/1) (at least in PCRE).

Comment: If you only want to match the spaces, it looks like you're lucky as the `regex` module seems to accept variable-width lookbehinds, which is rare. `(?<=\p{Han}+)\s+(?=\p{Latin}+\s+\p{Han}+)|(?<=\p{Han}+\s+\p{Latin}+)\s+(?=\p{Han}+)` should therefore work, it is an alternation of the two spaces of the pattern with the rest of the pattern as lookarounds.

Comment: You used a OR logical operator here. Is it possible to use a AND operator to avoid redundancy?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Remove or replace the two spaces from the matched pattern? If so, match the whole thing with `(\p{Han}+)\s+(\p{Latin}+)\s+(\p{Han}+)` then craft your replacement string using backreferences to the first, second and third capturing groups which will respectively contain the preceding chinese word, the english word and the following chinese word.

Comment: I want to remove these spaces.

Comment: Then match `(\p{Han}+)\s+(\p{Latin}+)\s+(\p{Han}+)` and replace by `\1\2\3`, as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/ptZp9l/2)

Comment: regex.sub("(\p{Han}+)\s+(\p{Latin}+)\s+(\p{Han}+)", "", string1), the output is "; ". Strange.

Comment: @JamesChang no that's quite expected, you've matched the pattern and replaced it by the empty string. Replace it by `\1\2\3` instead, i.e. `regex.sub("(\p{Han}+)\s+(\p{Latin}+)\s+(\p{Han}+)", r"\1\2\3", string1)`

Comment: I want to remove the \s+ in this regex but keep Han and LATIN. I think we're almost there.

Comment: Yes, that's what should happen with `regex.sub("(\p{Han}+)\s+(\p{Latin}+)\s+(\p{Han}+)", r"\1\2\3", string1)` ; what result are you getting? Did you check my last regex101 link to confirm it results in what you're expecting? (check the substitution panel, which shows the output after replacement)

Comment: Oh, I got you wrong. I typed regex.sub("(\p{Han}+)\s+(\p{Latin}+)\s+(\p{Han}+)", "", string1). Sorry. Your answer helped me! Would you please edit your answer and I'll mark it solved? Thank you very much!

Comment: @JamesChang already edited ;) And you're welcome !